# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with Vuejs and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Backend (nodejs)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization, Content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next(createError(404));
});
```

Frontend vuejs

```
  axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/uploadDocuments?access_token=`+store.state.token, 
      { 
          data: formData,
          //accessToken: store.state.token
      },
      { headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
          // 'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      }
    ).then (function (response) {
      this.potato = response.data 
    })
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/uploadDocuments?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.et: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the backend but the error still persists. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you see in the network requests that the header is actually being returned to the client? Worth checking.

Comment: Allow: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 03:28:00 GMT
ETag: W/"4-Yf+Bwwqjx254r+pisuO9HfpJ6FQ"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AeIZyLhwL8XaaeZoO6jByqsIcrG1B04CM.srODXDxbPwHwn7JwDFy5kq%2FC514bgrstQ5frX%2Bp3qc0; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 13 Aug 2019 03:28:00 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: Express

How do I know whether the header is actually being returned to the client ? @AlexTaylor

Comment: install chrome cors browser plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of what you have now

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT,POST,GET')
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install CORS

```
npm install cors
```

Now, include it into app()

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```